# Using cryptographic streams in C++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I'd like to use some cryptographic operations (mainly integrty check hashsums). However I have problems with finding documentations of doing operations of such form:

```
bool read(std::istream &in) {
    hasher hv(in);
    // Do some operations on hv as if it was std::istream
    hash_type h = hv.finish ();
    hash_type h2 = read_hash(in);
    return h == h2;
}
```

PS. It may be different library provided it a) is GPL-3-compatible b) works on GNU/Linux

PPS. I don't insist on crypto++ however I would like to have IOStream-like behaviour for interoperability with other C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Implement your own istream](http://spec.winprog.org/streams/) using crypto++.

Comment: I thought about it but I suspected someone might've done it before.

Comment: Actually, you implement your own istreambuf, not your own istream.

Comment: LInk is broken. [Link only answers are bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 6):

crypto++'s [FileSource](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html) class takes `std::istream&` in the constructor, so it seems that you are done.

```
FileSource (std::istream &in, bool pumpAll, 
    BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL)
```

**EDIT**

if you are asking `how to use a hash function on istream in cryptopp`, here's a sample taken from [cryptopp wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/fom-serve/cache/50.html), modified by me for use with `istream`:

```
#include "sha.h"
#include "files.h"

std::string digest;

CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;

CryptoPP::FileSource(in, true,   // true here means consume all input at once 
   new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash,
         new CryptoPP::StringSink(digest)));

std::cout << digest << std::endl;
```

This will read the stream `in` until eof, pass it through a `hash` filter and finally the result will enf up in the `digest` string.

Comment: But I cannot operate on the filtered date as on the std::istream.

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: I think that your question is not clear, then. Aren't you asking how to use cryptopp on streams? In your example you use `std::istream&`. Perhaps you are  asking how to use cryptopp's hash functions on streams? See my edit of the answer.

Comment: @davka: I'm asking how to get std::istream from cryptopp.

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: do you mean getting cryptopp **output** in the form of stream? Well, I see 2 options, before you dive into implementing your own stream: 1) use `FileSink` with `iostream`, have cryptopp write to it then rewind it before passing it as `istream` to another library; 2) use `StringSink` and create a `stringstream` with the string it writes to, and pass it on.

Comment: @davka: However it assumes I know the length of the hashed part or read whole stream from the beginning and it does not depend on the hashed content.

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: no, both options will pass on **only** the output of cryptopp. However, I think that your question is extremely underspecified - I am still not getting what is it you are trying to achieve. But never mind, as long as you got your answer ;)

Comment: @davka: Say I have an an xml file `<hashed><hash>789e403049261701b6caef9ccc679374</hash><content>|<content><content></content>|</content></hashed>` I'd like to be able to get a hash of text between `|` but the position of second `|` depends on the content hashed so I need to be able to mark in parser where hashing ends.