# MD5 and SHA1 C++ hashing library

Tags: c++, hash, md5, sha1

I'm trying to find a good (and well documented) hashing library to use with my C++ program, I only need to generate two hashes from a string.

I've tried with `crypto++` and `mhash` and I didn't manage to make them work, also with http://www.zedwood.com/article/121/cpp-md5-function

I would be glad if this library is cross-platform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best encryption library in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180870/what-is-the-best-encryption-library-in-c-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this open source library http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Search before ask, there is already question:
[What is the best encryption library in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180870/what-is-the-best-encryption-library-in-c-c)

Solutions like OpenSSL and Crypto++ are cross-platform, if you "didn't manage to make them work", you should have been more specific like: I use OS xyz version xyz, compiler xyz version xyz, IDE xyz version xyz, trying to get work library xyz version xyz from http://xyz, and it does not work, because xyz errors.

Answer (score 2):

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669306/using-cryptographic-streams-in-c/4671578#4671578). The original sample is taken from [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/fom-serve/cache/50.html), and operates on `std::string` rather than on `std::istream`. There are many good samples on cryptopp wiki, I'll try to look for some I used.

here's a sample from my code:

```
#include <cryptopp/md5.h>

byte digest[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
MD5().CalculateDigest(digest, (byte*)input.data(), input.size());
```

Here's the list of [cryptopp samples](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Category:Sample) on their wiki. Look at HashFunctions and HashFilter.