# Is there any C/C++ hash library (i.e python hashlib like)

Tags: c++, c, hash, cryptography

Well,

The title is pretty much my question, in python there is Hashlib, I'd like to know if there is any lib in C/C++ that have sha1, md5... implementations.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [MD5 and SHA1 C++ hashing library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678447/md5-and-sha1-c-hashing-library) or [What is the best encryption library in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/180870)

Comment: How did google not help you with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, given how pervasive use of these hashes is.  For example, OpenSSL has them; see [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html) and [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html) for basic documentation.

There are also standalone implementations; eg [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/src/?root=digest) is what I use in my [digest](http://cran.r-project.org/package=digest) package for R.